# How to make an executable from a python program with PyWin32 dependencies?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, python-3.8, pywin32

I made a python program that's dependent on some win32 libraries and now I want to bundle it into an executable.

PyWin is a rather strange library because you need to install the PyWin32 package but you use the submodules directly, and that is causing a lot of problems with pyinstaller.

The program always gets stuck on the line

```
import win32ui
```

because it can't find the win32ui module, as it's a submodule of the PyWin32 package and it (presumably) does some unusual things to import it in python, which pyinstaller can't seem to handle.

The program does run as is on my machine, it just causes problems with pyinstaller.

I already tried some random things I found online, like changing the line to `from PyWin32 import win32ui`, which just causes an error as PyWin32 isn't a module; importing pywintypes and pythoncom before win32ui, which doesn't seem to change anything; and forcing pywin32 in with pyinstaller commands like --hidden-import and --collect-submodules.

While I only tried using pyinstaller I'm open to other alternatives as long as they work and support python 3.8.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your results.  The app compiles and executes fine when using pyinstaller with the win32api.  Please create a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, I got the modules mixed up. It's actually win32ui that causes the error, not win32api.